# How do I do an Angular unit testing karma jasmine of this string function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Angular unit testing karma jasmine of this string function, layouts come from the backend (layout.ts) - it should return a string like (1-"ABC"-(active))

```
getSelectedLayout(): string {
const p = new ActivePipe();
if(this.layoutId === ''){
this.layoutId = this.layouts.find((x)=>x.status ===true)?.gridId.toString() as string;
}
const selectedLayout = this.layouts.find((x)=>x.gridId.toString() === this.layoutId);
return(
selectedLayout?.gridId + '-' + selectedLayout?.name + '(' + p.transform(selectedLayout?.status) + ')' ); }
```

Comment: Do you have your testing framework already set up?  If not, you should review the documentation in Angular/Karma/Jasmine to set up your development environment to do testing.

If you do have an environment setup, do you have your test files created (layout.spec.ts)?

If that file exists, then it should be just a matter of creating another test case.

Please provide more details of what you already have!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im in the step of creating another test case to test the method getSelectedLayout() from a component. The ActivePipe returns a value of 'active' or 'inactive' . I need to test that giving an array of values from the layouts , the method getSelectedLayout returns a string like  for example "1 - "ABC" - (Active)"